# How to declare protocol for HKT in swift?

Tags: swift, haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, when using `typeclass`, it is easy to declare constraint of its' instances' type kind.

```
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  ...
```

`* -> *` represents HKT (Higher-Kinded Types), this means any type conforming to `Functor` must be a HKT.

How can I achieve this with Swift's `protocol` ?

Answer (score 5):

Swift does not support HKT as a type form natively, but you can simulate the constraint with a trick of `associatedtype`:

```
public protocol Functor {
    /// (* -> *)
    associatedtype FA: Functor = Self
    /// *
    associatedtype A
    /// fmap
    func fmap<B>(_ f: ((A) -> B)) -> FA where FA.A == B
}
```

And conformance example:

```
enum Maybe<A> {
    case just(A)
    case nothing
}

extension Maybe: Functor {
    func fmap<B>(_ transform: ((A) -> B)) -> Maybe<B> {
        switch self {
        case .nothing:
            return .nothing
        case .just(let v):
            return .just(transform(v))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice documentation of a nice trick. Two comments: 1) I'd love to see some further explanation of why this is useful, possible applications (maybe built into the code examples) 2) why the use of `Maybe` as a type when we already have `Optional`?

Comment: @sjwarner `Functor` is a concept from functional programming. It is an abstraction of a way to apply a function over or around some structure that we don’t want to alter.  You may heard of `Monad`, it is a typeclass(protocol) based on `Functor`.

Comment: Absolutely, that's a good definition. But I'm assuming that by posting a question and self-answer, you're seeking to educate existing Swift users. Perhaps you'd see value in editing your question or answer to better convey to any readers not just _what_ a functor is, but also _why_ it's useful; what real-world problems can it be applied to? :)

Comment: @sjwarner the question is not about functor, it's about HKT constraint in protocol.

Comment: Note that using this approach you cannot prevent container altering, i.e you can write such Functor implementation that maps Array to Maybe for example, which is violation of functor rules (this part `associatedtype FA: Functor = Self` sets FA default to Self, but doesn't prevent altering it)